# How to insert data from notepad to MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad

I have text written in Notepad (Every statement is in a new line). I want to put the text in cells in Excel without losing any data. I want the lines to spread in cells rather than pasting them all in one cell. I don't know how many lines of text are there in the Notepad as there are many.

Example: The following is from Notepad

[image]

I want it paste it in excel to look like the following

[image]

Comment: Does simply selecting the text and pasting into Excel not work? What happens when you try? This has worked for me for many years and is a standard feature so I think you need to explain what is not working for you. If you double click a cell to edit it and **then** paste it will enter it as lines within a cell, if you simply single click a cell (and are not currently editing it then it should "just work".

Comment: And what does it look like now?  You need to provide all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Notepad: Select all text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or Edit > Select All)
2. Copy the selected text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or Edit > Copy)
3. In an empty worksheet in Excel: Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or Start > Paste)

All text will now be in column A, with each line in a separate row.

If you want to keep cell A1 empty, as in your screenshot, put the cursor in A2 before pasting.